# Returning a custom enumerable type from ObjectDataSource business class

Tags: asp.net, ienumerable, objectdatasource

This question might seem very basic but I am really very new to these aspects of C#. My apologies.

I am working on a ASP.NET 4 Web Forms application.

Here is my Book table

### Book

BookID (pk)
BookName
AuthorID
SubjectID
Copies

Here is my Author table

### Author

AuthorID(pk)
AuthorName

Subject table

### Subject

SubjectID(pk)
SubjectName

I have generated ADO.NET Model classes from these tables in the database.

I have created a Business Class for my **Book model** (containing CRUD methods) so that I can **use an ObjectDataSource to perform CRUD operations on Book**.

Here is the get method of my Business Class

```
public static IEnumerable<Book> GetAllBooks()
    {
        var result = from author in db.Authors
                 join book in db.Books on new { AuthorID = author.AuthorID } equals new { AuthorID = book.AuthorID }
                 join subject in db.Subjects on new { SubjectID = book.SubjectID } equals new { SubjectID = subject.SubjectID }
                 select new { BookID = book.BookID, BookName = book.BookName, Copies = book.Copies, AuthorName = author.AuthorName };


        return result.ToList();
    }
```

The return type of this method is IEnumerable but since I am returning a list of anonymous objects now, this return type is invalid.

I know I can solve this by extending the Book model class so that it contains AuthorName and SubjectName, and then using that model class, but I want to avoid writing more code.

Is there any other way I can return this anonymous object list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just return `IEnumerable<dynamic>` instead of `IEnumerable<Book>` if you really wanted the anonymous objects, but you're going in a bad direction here. When using the `GetAllBooks` method further up in your code you'll have no idea what properties these objects have and you'll have to go back to your business code to make sure - and even worse: The compiler won't help you at all catching typos. Try sticking to strongly typed objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Create class that will contains only this for properties:

   public class BookModel
   {
       int BookID{get;set;}
       string BookName{get;set;} 
       ? Copies{get;set;} 
       string AuthorName{get;set;}
   }

and use it instead of anonimous.
2. Create navigation properties to Author and to Subject in Book entity class and use Include() instead of Join() to get its data from db. Something like:

```
var result  = db.Books.Include(b=>b.Author).Include(b=>b.Subject);

return result;
```